# Get current running Activity in Android through <application> tag class

Tags: android

I have an Android application with 50 Activities i wont track current running activity in log-cat instead of creating ActivityManger in all activities or calling the instance object in each activity.

My thought is to create a non-activity class and append it to  tag in Manifest.xml so that it should track all the activities.

Comment: 50 activities? Something is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an Android Service and print the current activity from there.
For instance, the following service will run indefinitely with a 0.7 second timeout and print the current activity to LogCat:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

public static final String TAG = "Background Service";

public boolean wait;
public boolean stop = false;

SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(TAG, "On bind of service");
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stop = true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    (new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                update();
                return;
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    })).start();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

public void update() {
    List list;
    String str;

    do {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(701L);
        } catch (InterruptedException interruptedexception) {
            interruptedexception.printStackTrace();
        }

        list = ((ActivityManager) getSystemService("activity"))
                .getRunningTasks(1);
        str = ((android.app.ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo) list.get(0)).topActivity
                .getClassName();

        Log.d(TAG, str);
    } while (!stop);

    stopSelf();
}
}
```

You can also pass value to stop the service after some time. If you also want to know, how to start the service, then you can do the following on the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
startService(intent);
```

and do the following to stop the service:

```
stopService(intent);
```

Comment: Hey javanshir Thanks for quick reply.Could please provide any reference or sample

Comment: Let me know, if that doesn't work. However, everything should work :)

Comment: But i can't destroy service on pause and wake up the service on resume

Comment: I thought you will figure out how to stop the service. I modified the answer, just add the method `onDestroy` and call `stopService(intent)` when needed.

Comment: yes javanshir i already added it on my service class but my question is calling onPause and onResume like activity methods though these are not available in service class can we have any option to stop service onPause instead of stopping through Activity

Comment: Didn't understand your question. When exactly you want to stop the service?

Comment: i want to stop service when ever we click on home button like onPause() in Activity

Comment: put `stopService(intent);` inside `onPause()` of the activity. Then you just have to declare `Intent intent` outside of `onCreate`, but `intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);` inside `onCreate`

Comment: Can i get id of the button in service class for every click or touch listener done in other activities

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, and place it in the `Application` class:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static volatile String currentActivityName;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        currentActivityName = "MainActivity";
    }
}
```

And from every activities currently running, set:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    App.currentActivityName = "thisActivityName";
}
```

In manifest.xml:

```
<application android:name=".App"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    ...
</application>
```

To access currently activity running:

```
String activity = App.currentActivityName;
```